# Single Wsp From Multiple Wsp Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, visual-studio, wspbuilder

I have Sharepoint 2007 three Project. Each one have WSP.
Now I have to create single WSP from all of three WSP.

How to create One WSP from 3 different WSP in sharepoint 2007 using visual studio 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new project. Restructure the code from the earlier three projects in the new project so that only one WSP is created.

Comment: This is not the solution for me.
In sharepoint 2010 we create one package for all project and merge all wsp feature in to single wsp. Is that any way in 2007?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/multiple-sharepoint-projects-in-one-solution-how-to-package-correctly

Need this in 2007 using vs 2008

Comment: Oh got it. Not aware of any such workaround.